# Sound Design Studies?

Tags: design, studies, music

Hello everyone!

I'm currently looking for studies that have to do with Sound Design and I was wondering if anyone here knows a good university/school where they teach sound design or studies related to that (Music design etc.).
Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

In which country Leo?

I can vouch for Leeds Metropolitan University in Leeds, UK.

I'm just completing a MSc Sound Design there and the course was really good - very experienced tutors and brilliant facilities.

Good luck in your search!

Simon

Comment: I 2nd that! Studying down at Leeds Met was fantastic' Great tutors and facilities indeed! Love the 'Foley' room!


Answer (score 1):

Just finished sound design at the HKU in Hilversum. If your focus is only on film, look at the Nederlandse filmacademie in Amsterdam. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking into NFTS "National Film and Television School" London. If it is Sound Design orientated for the moving image then I would check this school out. It is the best in the Galaxy!
http://www.nfts.co.uk/courses/sound-design-for-film-and-television/Course
 Good Luck!!

Answer (score 1):

Edge Hill University offer a BA (Hons) Music & Sound undergraduate degree. Based between Manchester & Liverpool. It esp focuses on sound design, sound art, music composition for live performance & theatre.
http://www.edgehill.ac.uk/study/courses/music-and-sound-with-drama#summary_2011
Don't be put off by the title (which is due to change to Music & Sound in Theatre Performance....and is therefore all about designing & working with sound and music)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go in the direction of film, start by reading as much as you can from [filmsound.org](http://www.filmsound.org). It's a great source for material and inspiration on studying sound. Also with lots of book recommendations. Then while waiting for any place at any university, try to find an internship. In a company or just with a freelancer, if he/she is willing to take you on.

I learned so much from those two sources that it is at least equal to my studies if not more important for my today. I did study at the [HFF](http://www.hff-potsdam.de/) in Potsdam-Babelberg near Berlin. (which was still good, but less practical and basically just different)

Answer (score 0):

Hey Simon, thanks for the answer! I live in the Netherlands but I purposely did not put a  country in my post because I don't really care *where* it is, as long as its good. MSc sounds good, but that is only one year right? And 4000 pounds is certainly not cheap, but definitely looks good :)